# boost::interprocess::string conversion to char*

Tags: string, boost, char, interprocess

Is it possible to convert a `boost::interprocess::string` to an `std::string` or to a `const char*`? Something like `c_str()`...

E.g.:

```
boost::interprocess::string is = "Hello world";
const char* ps = is.c_str();    // something similar
printf("%s", ps);
```

I could even get a copy of the string in a non-shared memory block.

E.g.:

```
boost::interprocess::string is = "Hello world";
const char cs[100];
strcpy(cs, is.c_str());    // something similar
printf("%s", cs);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

boost::interprocess::string has a standard c_str() method. I found the following [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/interprocess/containers/container/string.hpp):

```
//! <b>Returns</b>: Returns a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters 
//!   representing the string's contents. For any string s it is guaranteed 
//!   that the first s.size() characters in the array pointed to by s.c_str() 
//!   are equal to the character in s, and that s.c_str()[s.size()] is a null 
//!   character. Note, however, that it not necessarily the first null character. 
//!   Characters within a string are permitted to be null. 
const CharT* c_str() const 
{  return containers_detail::get_pointer(this->priv_addr()); }
```

(That's for the `basic_string`. `string` is a template instantiation in which the `CharT` template parameter is `char`.)

Also, the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers) says

> basic_string is the implementation of
>   std::basic_string ready to be used in
>   managed memory segments like shared
>   memory. It's implemented using a
>   vector-like contiguous storage, so *it
>   has fast c string conversion*...

Comment: Thank you SCFrench. c_str() is what I tried at first, and I do not know why it didn't work. Now it is all right.